# Ways to automate JavaScript console output to increase understanding and debug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, automation, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I’m looking an efficient way to automatically output parsed data to the console for every script executed.

Using DevTools I’m not sure how to automatically change the logging level to have it output a stream of readable data.  The closest thing Ive found is

http://stritti.github.io/log4js/docu/users-guide.html

```
OFF     nothing is logged
FATAL   fatal errors are logged 
ERROR   errors are  logged 
WARN    warnings are logged 
INFO    infos are logged 
DEBUG   debug infos are logged 
TRACE   traces are logged 
ALL everything is logged
```

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what exactly you're looking for? I'm not sure I fully understand your requirement. You have Console API functions like `console.group` and `console.table` to group logs and tabularise data in the console.

Comment: There's a button in the console toolbar: [filtering](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#filtering_the_console_output)